# Loop through foreach statement and add into empty multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to populate an empty array with the name and value from a foreach loop. I've created an array `$variationimages = array();` and within the loop I'm saving the values by using `$variationimages['name']` and `$variationimages['image']`.

When returning the `$variationimages` array I'm only getting the first item

```
Array
(
    [name] = Wall Profile
    [image] = <img src="example-image.jpg">
)
```

What I would like is for it to return something like the below and to be able to access a specific item in the array by using something like `$variationimages['Roof Profile']['image']` which would return the image of the item with the name 'Roof Profile'.

```
 Array
    (
        [name] = Wall Profile
        [image] = <img src="example-image.jpg">
    ), 
(
            [name] = Roof Profile
            [image] = <img src="example-image.jpg">
        ),
```

The code I have is below:

```
function loop_display_variation_attribute_and_thumbnail() {
    global $product;

    // HERE your targeted product attribute taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'pa_product_type';
    $variationimages = array();

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {

            if( isset($variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
                // Get the "pa_product_type"
                $term_name = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name;
                $term_slug = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->slug;

                $variationimages['name'] = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name;
                $variationimages['image'] = '<img style="display:none;" class="'.$term_slug.'-image" src="' . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .'">';
            }
        }
        echo "<div style='display:none'>"; 
                print_r($variationimages);
                echo "</div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shaun, just add additional [] on your variable here:

```
$variationimages['name'][] = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name;
$variationimages['image'][] = '<img style="display:none;" class="'.$term_slug.'-image" src="' . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .'">';
```

On every iteration it will append new values.

Cheers ;-)

---EDIT after comment---

```
$variationimages[] = [
    'name'  => get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name,
    'image' => '<img style="display:none;" class="'.$term_slug.'-image" src="' . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .'">'
];
```

Comment: Hi @JohnnyB1988. Thanks for your answer. Ive added the code you mentioned but it's grouping the name and image values in separate arrays. I want both the name and image in a single array like my example above

Answer (score 0):

i think you must fill array with objects or array of arrays

like , you must create class for example Item   `$one_item= new Item();`

and write code like that:

```
function loop_display_variation_attribute_and_thumbnail() {
    global $product;

    // HERE your targeted product attribute taxonomy
    $taxonomy = 'pa_product_type';
    $variationimages = array();

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {

            if( isset($variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy]) ) {
                // Get the "pa_product_type"
                $term_name = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name;
                $term_slug = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->slug;
$one_item=New Item ();

                $one_item=>name = get_term_by('slug', $variation['attributes']['attribute_'.$taxonomy], $taxonomy)->name;
                $one_item=>image = '<img style="display:none;" class="'.$term_slug.'-image" src="' . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .'">';
array_push($variationimages,$one_item);

            }
        }
        echo "<div style='display:none'>"; 
                print_r($variationimages);
                echo "</div>";
    }
}
```